# IBM MobileFirst Hybrid JSONStore Not Encrypted After Key In ID and Password

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, jsonstore

I had input ID and password for JSONStore to initialize

```
var collection = {};
var option = {};
var VERSION_COLLECTION = "versionCollection";

option.username = "TESTID";
option.password = "TESTPASSWORD";
option.localKeyGen = false;

collection[VERSION_COLLECTION] = {
        searchFields : {
            "id" : "string",
            "name" : "string"
        }
};
WL.JSONStore.init(collection, option).then(function() {
    alert('ok');
}).fail(function(error) {
    alert(error);
});
```

It alert me ok. So I assume the initialization is ok. But when I open the TESTID sqllite files using sqllite browser, I managed to open the files successfully without prompting any error. It make no sense since 
https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSHS8R_7.1.0/com.ibm.worklight.dev.doc/devref/c_jsonstore_security.html
mention that if we provide a password when we initialize the JSONStore collection during 1st time init the sqllite will be encrypted.

I tried the JSONStore Hybrid samples in the IBM Website, the sqllite is encrypted.And I don't know where is the mistake I had done. Is there any other configuration need to be done in order to encrypt the sqllite?

Here is my MFP version

IBM MobileFirst Platform Studio 7.1.0.00-20150807-0630

Java 1.7

Thank You.

Comment: First thing first -you are using a year old build (from 2015). Download the latest iFix from IBM Fix Central, then remove and re-add JSONStore and try again.

Comment: Hi @IdanAdar I tried in IBM MobileFirst Platform Studio 7.1.0.00-20160401-2103 the sqllite still not encrypted.

Comment: Can you tell us what sqlite database you are using? I used http://sqlitebrowser.org/ in combination with the sqlite generate from JSONStore and was prompted with password request dialog. I used MFP 7.1

Comment: Yup, I am using the sqllite browser you mentioned.

Comment: @TerryChew, Provide a sample application where this is reproducible for you. Or the APK file maybe. Or better yet, the sqilite file.